# I want to add values from a range

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula

I have different names in range D2 to D130. The value I want to add are in range T2 to T130. I need to check if the name from column D belongs to the names in B2:B56. If the column D name is anywhere in column B, I will add the value from column T.

This is the formula I have: =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2, B2:B56, 0)), T2, "").

It outputs the value from T if D2 is in the lookup range. However, if the D2 value has more than one value in column D, it outputs a blank even if there is a value in T for both instances.

| Output | Lookup Range | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 238 | A | B | 263 |
|  | B | A | 238 |
|  | C | B | 105 |

How should I revise my formula to also get the sum of multiple instances of a name in Column D?

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation:

Since you are using `IF` on your formula it will only return the first instance of match and the rest will be ignore. We can use `SUMIF` instead of `IF`to sum the values of range depends on the criteria.

```
=SUMIF(D$2:D, B2, T$2:T)
```

This formula will add the values in column T when a name in column D matches the lookup range in column B.

### Sample Output:

[image]

### Reference:

- [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question, or if there are some clarifications needed so that I can adjust my answer accordingly.